# regex for extracting css rules and double curly brackets

Tags: php, css, regex

Currently I am separating css rules by using

`preg_match_all( '/(?ims)([a-z0-9s,.:()#_\-@>*]+){([^}]*)}/', $content, $arr);`

It's working fine. However, if I have double curly brackets like this

`@keyframes animationName1{0%{opacity: 0}100%{opacity:1}}div{opacity:0}@keyframes animationName2{0%{opacity: 0}100%{opacity:1}}`

this regex will not extract all of the animation rules due to the curly brackets within. I need suport in adapting said rule to look at the outer brackets and ignore the inner ones.

These should be the results:

```
1: @keyframes animationName1{0%{opacity: 0}100%{opacity:1}}
2: div{opacity:0} 
3: @keyframes animationName2{0%{opacity: 0}100%{opacity:1}}
```

Comment: No feedback on your [previous question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68344941/regex-capture-to-first-occurence-of-double-curly-brackets) ?

Comment: @Thefourthbird Thank you for your comments. I upvoted Tims comment as it solved the issue I had in the previous question. 

At first I wanted to filter out the double-bracketed rules and have come to the conclusion, I could adapt the rule to extract all css rules instead of filtering out the ones, that don't work with it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use

```php
([^{}]+)({((?:[^{}]++|(\g<2>))*)})
```

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/HELoxI/1/). *Details*:

- `([^{}]+)` - Capturing group 1: one or more chars other than `{` and `}`
- `({((?:[^{}]++|(\g<2>))*)})`  - Group 2:

  - `{` - a `{` char
  - `((?:[^{}]++|(\g<2>))*)` - Group 3: zero or more occurrences of any one or more chars other than `{` and `}` or Group 2 pattern (recursed)
  - `}` - a `}` char

See the [PHP demo](https://3v4l.org/MCsep):

```php
$text = "@keyframes animationName1{0%{opacity: 0}100%{opacity:1}}div{opacity:0}@keyframes animationName2{0%{opacity: 0}100%{opacity:1}}";
$rx = '~([^{}]+)({(?:[^{}]++|(\g<2>))*})~';
if (preg_match_all($rx, $text, $m)) {
    print_r($m[0]);
}
```

Output:

```php
Array
(
    [0] => @keyframes animationName1{0%{opacity: 0}100%{opacity:1}}
    [1] => div{opacity:0}
    [2] => @keyframes animationName2{0%{opacity: 0}100%{opacity:1}}
)
```

Answer (score 2):

If the format is always the same, you can also either match from 2 opening curly's till 2 closing curly's starting with an `@` or match word chars followed by a single opening till closing curly.

```
(?s)@\w+\h+\w+\s*{[^{]*{.*?}\s*}|\w+{[^{}]+}
```

- `(?s)` Inline modifier, make the dot match a newline (if on multiple lines)
- `@\w+\h+\w+\s*` Match `@` and 1+ word chars, spaces and again word chars
- `{[^{]*{` Match `{` then optional chars other than `{` and again `{`
- `.*?` Match as least as possible chars
- `}\s*}` Match `}}` with optional whitespace chars in between
- `|` Or
- `\w+{[^{}]+}` Match word chars and from `{...}`

[Regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/HRwpmL/1)

```
$re = '/(?s)@\w+\h+\w+\s*{[^{]*{.*?}\s*}|\w+{[^{}]+}/';
$str = '@keyframes animationName1{0%{opacity: 0}100%{opacity:1}}div{opacity:0}@keyframes animationName2{0%{opacity: 0}100%{opacity:1}}';
preg_match_all($re, $str, $matches);

print_r($matches[0]);
```

Output

```
Array
(
    [0] => @keyframes animationName1{0%{opacity: 0}100%{opacity:1}}
    [1] => div{opacity:0}
    [2] => @keyframes animationName2{0%{opacity: 0}100%{opacity:1}}
)
```